# Is there a good reference for ARM Neon intrinsics?

Tags: arm, intrinsics, neon

The ARM reference manual doesn't go into too much detail into the individual instructions ( http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348b/BABIIBBG.html ). Is there something that's a little more detailed?

Comment: As of yesterday, I started to write this (contributions welcome): https://github.com/thenifty/neon-guide

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: See also this for neon raw assembly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547697/coding-for-arm-neon-how-to-start/52920303#52920303

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For more information on the instructions themselves, you need the [Assembler Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0204i/Bcfjicfj.html).  The list you found there just shows the mapping from compiler intrinsics to assembly instructions.

Comment: The linked page is marked to be superseded, any idea where the updated version can be found?  Maybe [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/Badcdfad.html)?

Comment: @Antonion, your new link also superseded, nowadays. An update: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1361289932816.html

Answer (score 8):

There's also the [ARM C Language Extensions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053a/IHI0053A_acle.pdf) which provides details on the usage of the intrinsics (see chapter 12) that could be useful.

Answer (score 5):

There is now an [HTML version of the NEON Intrinsics Reference](https://developer.arm.com/technologies/neon/intrinsics) which is pretty convenient.  Each entry includes a link to a more detailed explanation of the relevant instruction.

It's still not quite as good as Intel's, which lets you filter by instruction set and includes pseudo-code implementations, but it's a huge improvement over the old PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

The [ARM NEON Intrinsics Reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0073b/index.html) lists every NEON intrinsic with a mapping to the instruction it behaves like. Like the reference you give, it doesn't go in to detail about the behavior of the instruction, so must be read together with an Architecture Reference Manual, but it is the most complete reference for NEON Intrinsics which I'm aware of.